# OnMessageReceived not called when sending data payload while app is killed on some device like OnePlus, Samsung

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

**I am sending notification as**

```
    {
  "to": "f52F8KB8TO-H0sGwtKiQmg:APA91bE3XPucTcDPMp09Q0gMypFOyfiqSOV22TNkZNo69p0-_CghDOhvBElQ4gf0eLWAGyKpeiJcDdjHkvJbzJXNOBrAUbZcFSXoRkkoNB_rZvpKYe9Jzj1tz7vAybkD1jqL2BTOwJBr",
  "priority": "high",
  "data": {
    "body": "App kill",
    "title": "Title",
    "meetingId": "12334",
    "type": "call"
  }
}
```

**I've declared Firebase Messaging Class in Manifest**

```
<service
            android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```